# JMS Message Acknowledgement Timeout?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

Does message acknowledgement use a timeout?

Is this implementation specific?

So for instance a broker delivers a message and never recieves an acknowledgment...period. At what point
does the broker decide enough is enough or does it ever?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is implementation specific. A broker can try to redeliver the message several times and then give up (and move the message to a dead letter queue).